# Visual Studio referenced project cannot find end point

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, azure

I am developing a VS 2010 project at the moment. I have a command line program "X" that makes calls to a webservice. This compiles and runs fine itself.

However, I am trying to use the classes of this command line program in a separate project "Y". To do this I have added a reference to project "X" in project "Y". All is good and both projects compile OK.

However, when it comes to running project "Y", the code falls over in project "X" because no end point could be found:

> "Could not find default endpoint element that references contract
>   'MyLocalService.MyServiceInterface' in the ServiceModel client
>   configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was
>   found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching
>   this contract could be found in the client element.

I assume this is something to do with the fact that the config files in project "X" have not been imported into project "Y"... but how do I do this?

Comment: Can you post some code and your config files so I can answer this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are right.  Configuration files (web.config and app.config) only apply to the process that is being executed.  In Visual Studio, you can control this by setting the start-up project for the solution.

It sounds like you need to create or copy the configuration for your service into project "Y".  And then run it.

Comment: Bingo. I have resolved this rather simply by adding exactly the same web service reference into Project Y as was in Project X. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a Service Reference to your project, this creates a section named `<system.serviceModel>` to your app.config or web.config (or adds config data to the `bindings` and `client` child nodes if it already exists).

You need to add this section from X's app.config to Y's app.config.